Docker cannot access my local apt repo at build time, but can at run time
I have a docker container running on my machine, hosting my own apt repo with aptly.
I need to make a Dockerfile that add it to it sources and download some packets from it.
I can ping it at build time, and get my repo key from it, but apt-get update time out.
If i bash into it and apt-get update at run time however, it works fine.
What could be the issue causing this ?
This is my docker file :
FROM ubuntu:24.04 AS base
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
ARG REPO_URL

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  wget \
  inetutils-ping

ADD http://${REPO_URL}/repo_signing.gpg /etc/apt/keyrings/my-soft.gpg
RUN chmod 644 /etc/apt/keyrings/my-soft.gpg

RUN ping ${REPO_URL} -c 4

RUN cat <<EOF > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mysoft.sources
Types: deb
URIs: http://${REPO_URL}/my-soft
Suites: noble
Components: main
Signed-By: /etc/apt/keyrings/mysoft.gpg
EOF

# This timeout when connecting to my repo
# RUN apt-get update

CMD ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]

And this is my docker compose:
services:
  app:
    image: buildenv:lastest
    build: 
      context: .
      args:
        REPO_URL: ${REPO_URL}
    env_file: .env
    network_mode: host

